# Alias for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace not recogized

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, namespaces, ms-word, office-interop

Here is my code in Form1.vb:

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
  ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oWord1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    Dim oWord2 as Application
```

I'm using VStudio2012 and Office 2010 and following the sample from https://support.microsoft.com/kb/316383

The declaration of **oWord** is flagged by intellisense as "Type 'Word.Application' is not defined,
while **oWord1** and **oWord2** are accepted. Intellisense provides several error correction options - two of which I've tried (oWord1 and oWord2) - the other options don't seem to apply.

In short, I am confused about why the use of the namespace alias Word on the Imports statement does not satisfy the syntax **Dim oWord As Word.Application** as described in the KB article. Is there some "master knob" to turn in the project properties dialog or something?

Comment: Have you tried to rename your alias to something different than the last leaf of the namespace? Something like `Imports WD = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`?

Comment: from what i've see Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word doesnt exist ad a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in refrences and then declare Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Comment: Steve, I just tried your suggestion. It works. So, am I right in concluding that the alias cannot be the same as the "last leaf" of the namespace? Apparently, it was formerly good syntax but now it is not? I can live with a quick global change of code from Word. to WD. but any thoughts on why?

Comment: Not really, it is just one of that thoughts that comes to mind. Quick to check and so you try it. And they end up to be correct.

Comment: Is the last leaf of your own current namespace 'Word'? I experienced a similar problem in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a reference to import the DLL for this namespace. In `Visual Studio 2012`, in your solution explorer` right click on the project name > click "Add Reference" > Choose "Assemblies" > "Extensions" > "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word". There may be multiple version of the Interop Libraries (Office 2003, 2007, 2010, etc), choose the appropriate one.

I believe these assemblies are originally installed when you do your installation of Microsoft Office from the DVD. So you will need to have Word installed I believe.

Edit: this works for me, with Intellisense:

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim oWord As Word.Application
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Yes, the reference was the first thing I added per the KB article. Thus, Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library was added; the path is C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll

Comment: Ok, I thought an easy solution might work. If it is helpful, I tested your code on my VS2012 with Office 2010 and the `declaration of oWord` does work for me. Intellisense is working also. I tried to intentionally mess the namespaces up, but I couldn't make it replicate your issue.

Comment: @John: the KB article is about an older version of the .NET Framework and Office in which things were done rather differently. In VS 2012 you would typically ensure you were targetting the more recent Framework (4.0 or 4.5 I should think) and then you select the reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word from the .NET tab, not the COM tab. I had very confusing results in the past along the same lines as you.

Comment: In VS 2013 it is missing in the express-version.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word' I used 'Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop' and it worked fine