# Using Word in vb.net error

Tags: vb.net

This VB.net code produces a not defined error.

```
Dim oWord As Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
```

Added line: `Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alias for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace not recogized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20911217/11683)

Comment: Did you reference the namespace? Just typing the import is not enough...

Comment: I did not reference the namespace.  How do I do that?

Comment: In the Solution Explorer, right click on References and choose Add.